# In python how to make a template . By taking input from user

Tags: python, templates

How to make a template in the form of a mail .in which takes input from the user and those inputs clearly mentioned in mail body also in python programming.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, welcome to SO. Could you please add the desired output in your post. It is not clear, if you want to create plain-text mails and what you mean by template. It is also not quite clear, what you mean by "which input takes from user". Do you really mean an input statement, or do you mean, that it should be read from a file (like csv), that the user provides.

Answer (score 0):

One simple attempt, in case you want to generate a plain-text mail (though I guess you also could use this approach for a html body).

Python some times is astonishingly simple.

```
name= input(prompt='Please enter the name of the receipient: ')
url= input(prompt='please enter the URL: ')
my_name= input(prompt='please enter your name: ')
mail_body= f"""
Dear {name},

we are proud to inform you, that we have just released a new version
of our anti-spam software, that reliably filters out unwanted mails
from your post box.

For more information please visit
{url}

Kind regards
{my_name}
"""
print(mail_body)
```